# Difference between Graphic() or a FeatureLayer() in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I've been adding paths and markers on my maps with the `Graphic()` service, but I know you can do it all with multiple `FeatureLayer()`.

What is the main difference between doing it all with one or the other?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-GraphicsLayer.html): "Unlike FeatureLayer and MapImageLayer, a GraphicsLayer has no schema. Therefore, the graphics that compose a GraphicsLayer may be of more than one geometry type (either points, lines, or polygons). Each graphic must have its own symbol since the GraphicsLayer cannot have an associated renderer. Graphics may also contain different attribute schema from one another." And "FeatureLayer has more capabilities than the GraphicsLayer, including rendering, querying, and labeling."

Comment: Are you using the 3.x or 4.x version?

Comment: I'm using 4.x, but I now understand the main difference, after having read the documentation a second time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @kenbuja:

> From the
>   [documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-GraphicsLayer.html):
>   "Unlike FeatureLayer and MapImageLayer, a GraphicsLayer has no schema.
>   Therefore, the graphics that compose a GraphicsLayer may be of more
>   than one geometry type (either points, lines, or polygons). Each
>   graphic must have its own symbol since the GraphicsLayer cannot have
>   an associated renderer. Graphics may also contain different attribute
>   schema from one another." And "FeatureLayer has more capabilities than
>   the GraphicsLayer, including rendering, querying, and labeling."