# Configuring UniqueValueRenderer to work with graphicsLayer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

**graphicsLayer** has a method: [setRenderer(renderer)](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/graphicslayer-amd.html#setrenderer)

How to set certain **graphic** elements of **graphicsLayer** using **UniqueValueRenderer**?
Any example available?
Did not find anything like this on Google therefore opened this issue here.
Using: **js arcgis 3.23**
Is this actually supported in **js arcgis version 3.x**?
As far as I know [it is not supported in **js arcgis version 4.x**](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/281189/121508)

Comment: Don't forget to to take the [Tour].  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Comment: Dear @PolyGeo [link] (https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/115/polygeo) - I found solution to my question and I have answered it. See: **"THE ANSWER: LINK"** that I added at the end of the original question as I did not find a way to publish it as the answer - probably because you placed my question on hold. I'm happy I managed to document this important issue as public SDK/manual coverage was missing. Good day!

Comment: The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50580955/uniquevaluerenderer-with-graphicslayer/50586315#50586315) you gave at [so] is code only, but if you plan to add some explanatory text to it here, then ping me and I can re-open to enable you to do so.

Comment: @PolyGeo - Yes I plan to add some explanatory text to it here. Thanks and have a good day!

Comment: It's re-opened now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not find a solution on the web so I had no choice but to investigate it on my own.
The main question was: how to talk to each graphic element that belongs to a certain graphicsLayer using UniqueValueRenderer.
Could not figure out from the ESRI js arcgis 3.23 API and examples what could be the right interface and syntax to use.
After experimenting a lot with the code came to the following conclusions:

1. Symbols defined at the Graphic layer always override symbols
   defined in a renderer. Therefore I instanced each Graphic using **no**
   Symbol.
2. In order to communicate with each Graphic separately UniqueValueRenderer needs to find some attribute on each Graphic therefore I added an attribute to each Graphic.
3. Now I attempted to use the Graphic attribute **name** in the UniqueValueRenderer while using Graphic attribute **value** to let UniqueValueRenderer select custom symbol for each Graphic.
4. The syntax for UniqueValueRenderer integration with graphicsLayer was not clear from the available documentation and ESRI examples but I experimented with various options and possibilities intuitively and I managed to make it work!

Here you can find the solution **[code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50586315/3593263)**.